# Can I connect an additional wire to HVAC system where all the terminals are full?

Tags: hvac, thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

I'm installing a new thermostat (ecobee Smart Si) and it requires "C" wire. I checked before I bought, and saw an unused blue wire behind my current thermostat. However after connecting everything the unit didn't power on. I checked the system in the attic, and found that the blue wire isn't connected. Here is a picture of the system. I planned to connect the blue wire to the "Com 24V" but **there's already a red wire there. Can I connect it anyway?** The red wire that's there goes to the outside unit I think.

[image: wires in hvac system]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, tapping along with the red wire under the (C)OM is where it goes. If you'll notice, your (Y) is already double taped.

Comment: OK, I'll give this a shot. Thank you very much!

Comment: No luck. I connected the blue wire to Com 24V along the red wire, but the new thermostat still didn't power on. I also tried removing the red, but still nothing. So I grabbed my multimeter, set it to ACV, and tested between R and Com24V, but it didn't register anything. Shouldn't it register as 24volts? What could cause it to not register?

Comment: @Joel Did you put the cover back on the furnace when you tested the new Tstat?

Comment: No. I'll try that. Just so I know, what does that do?

Comment: Ok, put the cover back on, checked all wires. It now reads 3.5v, whereas before it read 0.00, but still doesn't power on the thermostat.

Comment: It works! I started from scratch, disconnecting and reconnecting every wire, and poof!, it works. I believe that I  didn't have a good seat of the blue wire when I initially connected it to the Com24V. Either way, everything works now. Thank you very much for your time! (ps, I figured out what putting the cover back on does, where it pushes in a little tab to power on the unit. Thanks!)